# Passing parameters from one function to another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass my object in parameter when calling a function

```
lTemplate = "<input onkeyup='ClickedOne("+pCellule+")' type='text' value='" + pCellule.ValeurSaisie + "'";
//gb - Si la cellule est non editable
lTemplate += pCellule.StyleCellule.IsEditable == false ? " readonly " : "";
//gb - Appel la méthode de création du style CSS
lTemplate += CreateStyle(pCellule);
//gb - Ferme le template
lTemplate += "'></input>";


function ClickedOne(pInfo) {
    alert(pInfo); 
};
```

Doesn't seem to be working. Do you know why?
Because of quotes?
But when I put the outter the quotes (like `CreateStyle(pCellule)`) it works.
Merci!!

Comment: `pCellule` itself comes in parameter.

Comment: What content is `CreateStyle()` function? Can you provide a working jsfiddle.com ?

Comment: @DavidHaim any way outta this situation?

Comment: What is the type of `pCellule`? If it's a string, you need to put quotes around it.

Comment: if pCellule is an object it will not work like you are describing, it will only show Object.

Comment: pCellule is an object that contains lots of properties.

Comment: @OSDM yeah, I know. If it shows Object, that means my object passed. of I can test like: 

`function ClickedOne(pInfo) {
    alert(pInfo.ValeurSaisie ); 
};`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I can make it work in jsfiddle, its not gonna display anythind, cuz I'm using DTO, Json to send the data, using KOjs etc

Comment: Why are you adding `</input>`? `<input>` tags are self-closing.

Comment: @Alex McManns When it shows Object is means it was not able to do anything with it. When you alert({}); it shows: Object, that means it can not print because it is an object. Then you first need the JSON.stringify function, and then in your function the JSON.parse function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert `pCellule` into the Javascript syntax for an object literal:

```
lTemplate = "<input onkeyup='ClickedOne("+JSON.stringify(pCellule)+")' type='text' value='" + pCellule.ValeurSaisie + "'";
```

Note that the parameter passed to the function will be a copy of the `pCellule` object, because we converted it to JSON first. If you need to pass the object itself (so that `ClickOne` can modify it), you can't do it as text. You need to operate on DOM elements directly, rather than HTML strings, e.g.

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = 'text';
input.value = pCellule.ValeurSaisie;
input.onkeyup = function() {
    ClickedOne(pCellule);
}
if (!pCellule.StyleCellule.IsEditable) {
    input.readonly = true;
}
templateDiv.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` works absolutely fine! I passed my object, and can have an access to all its params.
Thank you! God bless!

Comment: what is `templateDiv` in your case sir? how did you declare it?
Im doing `lTemplate.appendChild(input)`, it doesn't seem to be working!!

Comment: It's the DIV that you want to put this HTML into. `var templateDiv = document.getElementById("templateID")`

Comment: my case is a little different, so I'm simply replacing this:

`lTemplate = "<input type='text' value='" + pCellule.ValeurSaisie + "'";
lTemplate += "'></input>";`

by this:

`var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.value = pCellule.ValeurSaisie;
return input;`


DOESN'T WORK!

Comment: What are you doing with the return value of the function? It returns a DOM element, so you need to use `appendChild()` to add it to the DOM, you can't assign it to `innerHTML` like the string.

Comment: I'm using DataTable and KnockoutJS.

Declaring my column
`var columns = [
        {
            name: "First property", data: "ListeData.0", render:
                function (data, type, full) {
                    return CreateTemplate(data);
}]`
<br/>

in my `CreateTemplate(pCelule)` I'm getting data formatted, and send it back.
Bin
<br/>
`<thead>
            <tr data-bind="foreach: columns">
                <th data-bind="html: name"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to integrate this answer with that library.

Comment: Thank you anywhere, you helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code will only work if pCellule is and integer, any other content will not work.

If it is a string, you have to put quotes around it and it will work.

If it is an object as you are writing at the top of your question then that is not possible, because you are first printing this, which will show: Object, because you are trying to print an object.